# Automatic completion

Tags: excel

Is there a way to reach the second picture automatically?

[image: is situation img]

[image: second picture]

Google Doc Example.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eKpvC9I59l3zGmzYhSHE5UU9yFMMxCcuQ6Ww2zoCf6Q/edit?usp=sharing

Direct example:

cell [3] -> A

cells [4,5,6,7,8,9] -> empty

cell [10] -> B

cells [11,12,13,14,15,16]  -> empty

What i need automatically:

cell [3] -> A

cells [4,5,6,7,8,9] -> A

cell [10] -> B

cells [11,12,13,14,15,16]  -> B

Comment: Should the data in all the cells be the same or increase sequentially?

Comment: Nope. No increase. Only duplicate until the next number.

Comment: Do you have multiple columns and you want to do this automatically over all columns? It's trivial to do this manually if there's only one clump

Comment: One column. 700 data records. manually I'll do this for days... :D

Comment: So al values in cell 3..9 should be the same, then 10 is different, then 10..16 is the same?

Comment: (You should make a [mcve] instead of using your real data then use black marker to hide sensitive data. Just use things like [3] = 'a', [4..9] = empty, [10] = 'b', etc.)

Comment: I edit my question and include one G Doc Example

Comment: links doesn't count. Include the details directly in the question.

Comment: did it.. I hope you can understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the data is in column A.

In column B you should use the formula:

```
=if(isblank(a3),b2,a3)
```

You use this formula for the entire range which you want filled. You fill it in B3, hit . Then copy / paste the B3 cell to the entire range down.

That should do it.

Note: you cannot use this approach in-place. You need to create the "beautiful" data in a separate temporary range, and then do a copy / paste of values-only of the beautiful data into the original range. After that, you can delete the temporary range.

[image]

---

An alternative is the following:

In the empty cells use the formula:

```
=a3  (in cell a4)
=a4  (in cell a5)
```

and so on (cell ranges taken from attached screenshot, not from Google Docs)

Comment: I am not sure I understand. "Unused"?

Comment: Doesn't work anyway. You can see it in my google doc.

Comment: Some voodoo happened. Some comments disappeared, including one of mine. @user202729 - I commented earlier exactly the same thing - using a temporary range and then copy / paste of values only..

Comment: I found the anweser. =WENN(ISTLEER(A4);B3;A4)

Comment: :))) Not working because of using the German variant of Excel :))

Comment: @user202729: I added a note in the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @JvdV: I understand that the two formulas have the same intent, but writing English formulas in German Excel is not going to work.

Comment: @virolino, exactly, my point is that OP said he found this to be the answer. If this has answered his question he should mark it as such, acknowledging your effort.

Comment: I agree, he should choose this as the correct answer in this case.